# Can't get SINGLE_TABLE inheritance to work in Spring Roo.

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-roo

I'm using Spring Roo with Oracle to map an inheritance hierarchy using SINGLE_TABLE inheritance.  Roo database reverse engineering created this class. I added the @Discriminator... annotations and the inheritanceType.

```
@RooDbManaged(automaticallyDelete = true)
@RooJpaActiveRecord(inheritanceType = "SINGLE_TABLE", table = "MEASUREMENT", schema = "SCREENING", sequenceName = "MEASUREMENT_SEQ")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 50)
@DiscriminatorValue("TEXT")
public class Measurement {
    ...
}
```

Roo built Measurement_Roo_DbManaged.aj with

```
privileged aspect Measurement_Roo_DbManaged {
    ...
    @Column(name = "DTYPE", length = 50)
    @NotNull
    private String Measurement.dtype;
    ...
}
```

and Measurement_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj with

```
declare @type: Measurement: @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE);
```

(If you're not too familiar with Roo, these bits are folded into the main class before it's compiled.)

I then created the subclass

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="NUMERIC")
public class MeasurementNumeric extends Measurement {
    public MeasurementNumeric(Long value) {
        setNumericValue(value);
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I start the app, it throws a BeanCreationException on context initialization which is eventually caused by

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: my.package.domain.MeasurementNumeric column: DTYPE (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false") 
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:682)
```

I have been trying to figure out what's happening here all day and I'm getting nowhere.  The only other times I've seen this error mentioned have been when someone declared @Column(name="someName") on more than one property simultaneously.  But I don't see how that could be happening in this case.

Can somebody give me a clue on what's going on and how to fix it?